Lithium 3S2P, possible faulty BMS?
I have a pool robot that stopped working. Pulled it apart and there's a lithium battery pack with 6 cells. The label states it is 10.8v, so I assume 3S2P.
The pack has a BMS mounted on it. When I check voltage using the BMS charge/discharge port, I only get 4.1v.
If I check each pair of cells directly they all have 4.1v. When I check end-to-end directly on the cells I get a reading of 12.3v.
Is this an indication that the BMS is faulty?
Thank you!

The label gives a nominal value, possibly a minimum for acceptable function.   You can't determine a fault without operational conditions and measurement tolerances.
